# How to retrieve the name of an existing key vault using ARM templates

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault, azure-rm-template

Assuming that there is a key vault in my resource group, is there any way that in another template I could somehow get the name of the key vault (dynamically)? Assuming that I do know the subscription id, the resource group name and maybe other properties if needed.
Thanks ahead.

Comment: If you wanna using key vault secret in your template, you need to specify the key vault name, so it's impossible to set a dynamically name.

Answer (score 0):

Nope. Knowing the name of the resource is mandatory for you to be able to reference it in some form in your ARM template.

Even for using a Template function like [resourceId](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-functions-resource?tabs=json#resourceid) that has the following signature:

```
resourceId([subscriptionId], [resourceGroupName], resourceType, resourceName1, [resourceName2], ...)
```

You would notice that the resource name is a required parameter. Knowing the other parameters like Subscription ID and resource group name are optional.

If there is no hard requirement for you do this within an ARM template only, you could go about using Azure PowerShell/Azure CLI commands to first get/list the resource, and then extract the name to pass it on to your ARM template as a parameter.